# c++ stack alignment for one specific call

Tags: c++, assembly, memory-alignment, stack-pointer

I have a global function `func()` implemented in assembly, declared as an external in a C++ source file:

```cpp
extern "C" void func(char*);
```

`func()` requires the stack to be aligned at 32 bytes. Now, I could:

1. Force all my calls to be aligned at 32 bytes passing the appropriate flag to the compiler
2. Align the stack in the assembly source of `func()`
3. Somehow force the calls to `func()` to be aligned at 32 bytes instead of a default of 16.

I don't want to do 1. So my question is, how to do 3? Perhaps the most efficient way is to just enforce alignment, as in 2.

Comment: If you expect ABI-conforming code to call your function, you should probably build your function in a way that is ABI-conforming i.e. expecting 16-byte alignment and adjusting if necessary to get to 32-byte alignment.

Comment: You have to do 2.

Comment: @ThomasJager yes, that is 2. above, but still would like to know the answer to my question as to how to do 3?

Comment: @ReimundoHeluani 3 can't be done on a per-call basis at the call site, only *inside* the function itself, as in 2. My question to you is - WHY does `func()` require the stack to be aligned at 32 bytes?  Why can't it just use whatever alignment the compiler wants to use?

Comment: You can not do (3) in C++. Your only option is (2) with convenience band-aid: you can create a call_func() in ASM, which aligns stack to 32 bytes and than calls func.

Comment: Thanks, this is an unexpected answer to my question, but is a full answer then if it can't be done from the C++ code. @RemyLebeau it's a vectorized algorithm, and having the stack aligned at 32 bytes makes life easier (since most of the vector operations require this alignment on memory operands). I don't mind doing 2, but since the code is based on an external library, maintaining the fork becomes a little more complicated.

Comment: So @SergeyA's approach seems the simplest from a maintaining perspective instead of changing the code directly in func.

Comment: There obviously isn't portable ISO C++ syntax for calling convention details like that (which might not even exist on some hypothetical implementations that implement function args totally differently from the asm stack in a modern mainstream systems.)  But there are ways with specific compilers or specific calling conventions to make this happen; I think there might be a GCC `__attribute__` to control this.  There is for telling the compiler about incoming alignment maybe being less than 16.  So do you want a compiler-specific answer?  If so, which compiler, and which calling convention?

Comment: But yeah, it only takes a couple instructions to align the stack inside a function, especially if you don't need VLAs in that function, and/or if you were already making a frame pointer anyway.